# Oracle SQL, insert DATE with "YYYY-MM-DD" format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE horario (
    id_horario  NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    time_start  DATE NOT NULL,
    time_end    DATE NOT NULL,
);
```

I want to insert a time_start or time_end with type '08:00:00' but DATE receives "YYYY-MM-DD" format, I need to chage the type for `time_start` and `time_end`.

What should be the data type for those times?

EDIT:

Currently I have this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34b50/10

But I need to insert only the time

Comment: It usually isn't a good design to store time separately, by itself.  What would be wrong with using timestamps here?

Comment: Yes, but those rules are not mine. I was thinking on using something like `TO_CHAR( date_field, 'HH24:MI:SS' )` at INSERT

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *with type '08:00:00'*. You can certainly store 08:00:00  in a `DATE` column, along with a date.

Answer (score 0):

You may either continue storing time along with date, and during retrieval, you may extract just the time portion out of it.

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(time_start, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_CHAR(time_end, 'HH24:MI:SS')
FROM horario;
```

Or, you may change the type to VARCHAR2 and while inserting, extract just the time portion and save that.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your *profile*, looks like Oracle isn't one of your top tags. That's probably why you want to do it in a wrong manner. Well, don't do it.

Oracle doesn't have `time` datatype. Your choice would be `date` (as table `horario` already suggests). Do not pick `char` or `varchar2`, fooled by impression that *hey! I can store `10:30` in there!* is correct, because it is not. Nobody stops you from inserting e.g. `13$f6` into such a column. It is also 5 characters long, but certainly doesn't represent *time* value.

Furthermore, you can't perform any date arithmetic with strings; first, you'd have to convert those strings into valid `date` values and then do the arithmetic. But, sooner or later (as we frequently see on various Oracle forums, SO included) you'll find some garbage in that column which will cause headache.

Therefore: store (full) date value, but **select** it in a format that suits you most. See the following example:

```
SQL> create table horario
  2    (id_horario number,
  3     time_start date);

Table created.
```

`sysdate` is a function that returns current date and time.

```
SQL> insert into horario (id_horario, time_start) values (1, sysdate);

1 row created.
```

What's being inserted?

```
SQL> select * from horario;

ID_HORARIO TIME_STA
---------- --------
         1 09.06.21
```

Huh? Didn't I say it returns both date AND time? So where's time? It's here, but my session settings prevents us to see it. One option to "fix" that is to use `TO_CHAR` function with desired format mask, for example:

```
SQL> select id_horario,
  2         to_char(time_start, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') time1,
  3         to_char(time_start, 'hh24:mi') time2
  4  from horario;

ID_HORARIO TIME1               TIME2
---------- ------------------- -----
         1 09.06.2021 10:16:35 10:16
```

Another option is to change date format for the session, e.g.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from horario;

ID_HORARIO TIME_
---------- -----
         1 10:16

SQL>
```

So, yes - use `date` datatype, format values as you want.

Comment: Ok, my question was for a friend that is learning Oracle, I haven't used it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND` to store time values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE horario (
    id_horario  NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    time_start  INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND NOT NULL,
    time_end    INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND NOT NULL
);
```

Then you can insert the values:

```sql
INSERT INTO horario ( id_horario, time_start, time_end )
VALUES ( 1, INTERVAL '08:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND );
```

This allows you to subtract the values to find a duration or to add them to `DATE` values as needed.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=33bfb7bbf7aa8025172881754c51db9d)*